# How do I cancel a running migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a *Ruby On Rails* app I ran `rails db:migrate`, and for some reason the migration hung. I ended up  having to kill the terminal tab in which the migration was run. When I tried to run `rails db:migrate` in a new tab, I received this error message:

> Cannot run migrations because another migration process is currently running

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5 db migration: how to fix ActiveRecord::ConcurrentMigrationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976556/rails-5-db-migration-how-to-fix-activerecordconcurrentmigrationerror)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop and then restart the database again. Then try `rails db:migrate` again.

If you are using posgresql installed with homebrew on Mac OSX the following stops/restarts the database:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

Comment: Restarting the database might not be something that you "just do" in a production environment. Releasing the lock might be more appropriate in that case, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976557/119937

Answer (score 12):

If you are using postgresql in linux based system, you can use below command to restart the database. Then run your migrations again.

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```